# Is there a way to create Google Apps Trigger in Google account level and not specific to one Form?

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-forms

I have created a Trigger on Form submission to call a Post API with the responses from the Google form as Payload.
This works fine on the form.
Now I have to integrate the same trigger with all the Google forms I create in my google account.
Is there a way where the Trigger automatically adds to the form once I create ?
There are more than 10 forms to be created and same trigger has to be added to all the forms. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to create a trigger with the same instructions for multiple forms, you might want to use something similar to this:

#### Code

```js
function createTrigger() {
    let ids = [FORM_ID1, FORM_ID2, ...];
    for (let i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
        var form = FormApp.openById(ids[i]);
        ScriptApp.newTrigger('onFormSubmit')
            .forForm(form)
            .onFormSubmit()
            .create();
    }
}

function onFormSubmit() {
    //trigger function here
}
```

#### Explanation

The above code is composed of two functions:

- `createTrigger` > this is used to create a trigger for each form; in order for this to execute properly, you will have to supply the form ids you need to have the trigger for;
- `onFormSubmit` > this is the function that gets executed when any of the forms supplied above receive a response.

#### Reference

- [Apps Script FormTriggerBuilder Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/form-trigger-builder);
- [Apps Script Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable).

Comment: Thanks Ale for the information. But still we need to enter all the form ids here. Isn't there any other option skip entering the form ids and pick all the form ids by account. ?

Comment: No, you will have to specify exactly which forms are needed for this - hence the `ids` variable from the script.

Comment: Yes Ale. This answered my question.